# Maximise a function in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to maximize a function I created.

```
>n <- 183
>sll <- c(0.1,0.1,0.1)
>newtransform <- numeric()
>newadstock <- numeric()
>sales <- c(0.1790,0.27,0.46,0.134,0.338)
```

This is a function which I created:

```
>calc.fun <- function(sll,x) {
>          for (i in 1:n) {
>                   newtransform[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-sll[1]*(x[i,1] - sll[2]))) -
>                       1/1+exp(-sll[1]*-sll[2])
>          }
>          newadstock[1] <- newtransform[1]
>          for (i in 2:n){
>          newadstock[i]  <- newadstock[i-1]*sll[3] + newtransform[i]
>          }
> -cor(sales,newadstock)  
>}
```

I want to maximize this correlation value, so I tried to use the optim function, which gave me an unfavorable result.
Here I'm modifying the parameters of the `sll`vector and the constraints for this vector are mentioned in the lower and upper parameters

`>optim(sll, calc.fun, lower = c(0.1,0.1,0.1), upper = c(1,25,1), method="L-BFGS-B", x=scaled_tarps)`

Output

```
>$par
[1] 0.1885345 0.1000000 0.5709148
>$value
[1] -0.7622432
```

How do I improve my correlation value?Should I change the `method` parameter? Or should I use some other R function like `optimx`?

Edit - Question has been edited to remove any mention of `Excel`.

Comment: `optim` searches for *minimum* of the function and you use `-cor` as your criteria for minimum, so -0.76 is 0.76 correlation... It is lower than 0.85 but positive.

Comment: It may be. But I expect a result much closer to the solver output. Also the 2nd parameter value still maintains its initial value of 0.1, whereas excel gave me a value of 6.9 satisfying the constraint < 25.

Comment: Two different algorithms gave you two different solution - it happens... Maybe there are local minima? You could always try different algorithms.

Comment: @Tim It is possible. But if I enter these parameter values in excel, the correlation value is 0.81, rather than the 0.76 which I got above, which doesn't make sense to me. So, I'm guessing that something is wrong in my algo.

Comment: We do not know anything about your data, your Excel algorithm and about what you wanted to achieve, so it is impossible to say if your approach is "correct". Only thing that is known is that you made some algorithm that does something with some efficacy and it gives different output than Excel one.

Comment: @Tim I have edited the question removing any mention of Solver or Excel. If this algorithm can be improved, please do suggest.